# Is there a way of randomising which if statement runs first,second,third,fourth and so on in Java?

Tags: java

If I have a bunch of if statements:

1. if(){}
2. if(){}
3. if(){}
4. if(){}
   etc....

Is there a way that these if statements can be run randomly instead of top to bottom? For example, if() statement 4 may run first and if() statement 2 may run last and other possibilities.

Comment: Why would you need this? There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Sharing the context of the problem you're trying to solve will surely attract more useful answers.

Comment: Why you want it to randomly  execute, If you have a specific problem please share it.

Comment: To sort elaborate on the three comments above, yes there are ways, but those ways often depend on the actual problem context.  More information would help us help you better.

Comment: Have you thought about it? There are n!=24 combinations of which runs 1st, 2nd,....

Comment: As a sequence of statements, no. As an indexable collection of *tasks* -- yes.

Comment: Hm, this *must* be an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuffle an array of 0...n integers. Each number represents one of your `if`-statements.

[Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

```
int[] indices = shuffleRandomArray(0, 10);
for(int idx=0; idx<indicies.length; idx++) {
  int val = indicies[idx];
  if(val==0) if(){..};
  else if(val==1) if(){..};
  else if(val==2) if(){..};
  else if(val==3) if(){..};
  else if(val==4) if(){..};
  ...
}
```

In Java 8 you could use function pointers https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator